# SQL Adaptive Query?

Tags: sql

I have data that I need to pull on a fairly frequent basis.  Most data pulls have been fairly straight forward (for me).  This next one is probably straight forward for experienced SQL writers, but I'm lost.  I'll try to paraphrase. Below, I have two tables.

**Table1: Samples**

| Sample Field | Other Crap |
| --- | --- |
| Distinct Sample 1 | 25 other parameters in other fields |
| Distinct Sample 1 | 25 other parameters in other fields |
| Distinct Sample 1 | 25 other parameters in other fields |

**Table2:  Results**

| Sample Field | code | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Distinct Sample 1 | code1 | NEGATIVE |
| Distinct Sample 1 | code19 | POSITIVE |
| Distinct Sample 2 | code2 | NEGATVE |
| Distinct Sample 2 | code3 | NEGATVE |
| Distinct Sample 2 | code4 | POSITIVE |
| Distinct Sample 2 | code16 | NEGATIVE |
| Distinct Sample 3 | code1 | UNSAT |
| Distinct Sample 3 | code3 | NEGATIVE |
| Distinct Sample 3 | code4 | POSITIVE |

I'm trying to write an adaptive query that would display the following:

| sample | code1 | code2 | code3 | code4 | code16 | code19 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| distinct sample 1 | NEGATIVE | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | POSITIVE |
| distinct sample 2 | NULL | NEGATIVE | NEGATIVE | POSITIVE | NEGATIVE | NULL |
| distinct sample 3 | UNSAT | NULL | NEGATIVE | POSITIVE | NULL | NULL |

Not every sample will have the same codes.  Some samples have 50+ codes.  Many samples will have the same codes.  Some will have less, some will have more.

What I've done so far:

- Created query to load samples I want to see (there are 100s of thousands of samples) into temp table.  table is #tmpspecs and it's one column.
- Created a query to determine a list of all distinct codes for the sample subset.  So, for the 200 samples I want to see, I'm gathering ALL the possible codes. table is #tmprcs and it's one column.
- I tried to make a query to pull the data but it needed individual sub selects for each code.

I'm clueless as to what to do next...I tried to create a string with all of the codes and then parse it out to create sub queries but I couldn't figure out how.  Is this easy?

Comment: I think the first table should have 3 DIFFERENT values in the first column.  -- Sameple 1, Sample 2, Sample 3.  Right?

Comment: Please provide the queries you've tried thus far.

Comment: SQL is strongly typed. That includes the dataset definition/signature. Dynamic columns are intentionally NOT part of SQL; what you're trying to achieve is an anti-pattern. So that begs the question, WHY are you trying to do this?

Comment: You need to do a dynamic CROSSTAB or a PIVOT (CROSSTAB is usually more performant and it's a technique, not a function or operator).  Since not all SQL engines are equal and this is a generic tag you've file under, what engine are you using and what version?

Comment: @Hogan.  Yes, it should.

Comment: @MatBailie because it's needed of course...

Comment: @JeffModen I'll look into those functions!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a pivot or you can do it as follows using left joins.  Internally they are the same and I think the left join method is clearer.

```
SELECT s.sample, r1.result as code1, r2.result as code2, r3.result as code3, r4.result as code4, r5.result as code5
FROM Samples S
LEFT JOIN results r1 on r1.sample = S.sample and r1.code = 'code1'
LEFT JOIN results r2 on r2.sample = S.sample and r2.code = 'code2'
LEFT JOIN results r3 on r3.sample = S.sample and r3.code = 'code3'
LEFT JOIN results r4 on r4.sample = S.sample and r4.code = 'code4'
LEFT JOIN results r5 on r5.sample = S.sample and r5.code = 'code5'
```

Note -- I did codes 1 to 5 here.  If you want different codes just follow the pattern

Comment: Thank you.  What if I don't know what codes will be present?  There are thousands of codes :)

Comment: @warriorfrogz Then pivoting your data like this is a SQL Anti-Pattern, keep the normalised structure, that's the pattern SQL is designed for

Comment: @warriorfrogz -- Do it on the client or use dynamic SQL -- but really you are planning on having a result table with thousands of columns?  Something does not add up.

Comment: @Hogan the table has millions of rows.

Comment: @MatBailie not sure what you mean.  not an expert.